# How do I get the smoothest animation possible in iOS?

Tags: ios, uiview, core-animation, core-graphics

I'm using the `UIView` method `animateWithDuration:animations` to animate sliding a `UIView`. It appears slightly choppy. Is there a better method, like CoreGraphics, to accomplish a smoother animation?

Comment: If all you're doing is sliding a view, animateWithDuration is a perfectly good choice and should lend suitable results. If it seems choppy, there may be another issue you're missing. Another approach to animation would be to use something like a CABasicAnimation, which may be added to the layer of the view you're trying to animate/slide as you shift a layer's position property (or another animatable property of CALayer).

Comment: You should look into how many subviews this view has (labels, images, etc.) that all count towards it's overhead. If these views are not opaque the animation performance may take a hit. Also be careful with testing performance of animations in the simulator on Mac with an older or crappy grahics card. I have seen the Retina Simulator have choppy animations, but the animations are smooth on an actual device.

Comment: Note that iOS Core Animation is often pretty choppy on the simulator, but runs smoothly on the device. Make sure you test on the device. Also make sure you test your app running NOT tethered to Xcode, since the debugger can slow things down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use different `UIViewAnimationOptions`

The default is `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut`, but you can try others:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     v.center = CGPointMake(400, 400);
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                 }
 ];
```